# View Code turns into Binary Characters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I was writing code in a view when power went off and my machine shut down.
On powering up the machine again, all my View Code had turned into some sort of Binary Code.
This is the 2nd time its happening and the last time I re-wrote the code but isn't there a better way to recover my code?

Comment: so the file you were working on got corrupted is what you're saying?

Comment: Source control. This is why it exists. Visual Studio supports both TFS and Git now. Pick your favorite and commit your changes regularly. Then, when something like this happens, you can pull the last good version down and take off.

Comment: JamesS yeah.
@ChrisPratt I use Visual SVN, its just that this happens when I have some un commited changes,just thought there would be a way to decode the code.